# Не работает ScrollView

Tags: android, scrollview, focus

Не работает `ScrollView`. Думаю, связано с наличием `EditText` на том же экране. *Примечание* `GridView` - `layout` с айтемами, их много. Когда нажимаю на поле, то всё работает, но когда выхожу из редактирования текста в поле, `ScrollView` перестает работать. Всё как-то связано с фокусом, но я не знаю как пофиксить. Код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tv" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="lenght"
        android:id="@+id/lenght" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Create"
        android:onClick="create"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <GridLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:columnCount="5"
            android:id="@+id/images">
        </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена - все дело было в том, что Android studio не перестанавливала приложении через USB, нужно было сначала удалить приложение на телефоне, а потом скомпилировать и установить его.

Comment: А какую версию Android Studio используете?

Comment: Dmitry, 2.1.3, build AI-143.3101438